# Trying to move my blog title up

Tags: css, blogger

I am trying to move my blog title up a little higher. If you will look at my blog you will see that the title & subtitle are too far down.

http://www.melissavenable.blogspot.com

The title (Little Mrs. Married) should be in the turquoise area above the pink line & the subtitle (some things...) should be right under the pink line, but still above where it is now. It was suggested me to put this

```
.descriptionwrapper {padding-bottom: 50px;}
```

or this

```
.descriptionwrapper {margin-bottom: 50px;}
```

in the HTML code above where it says  but that didn't work. Any other ideas?

Thank you! 
Melissa

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove

```
padding: 60px 0 0;
```

in your `#header h1` style.

Should look like:

```
#header h1 {
    margin:5px 5px 0px 20px;
    line-height:1.2em;
    text-align:left;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:.2em;
    font: normal normal 220% 'Times New Roman', Times, FreeSerif, serif;;
}
```

Comment: That moves it too far up... the subtitle should still be in the white area... she needs a top padding of 30px as my earlier answer suggests.

Comment: Ok, so she can adjust it however she wants, but there's no need for the downvote.

Comment: Nothing personal... the answer was incorrect and late and had been upvoted. If she could "adjust it however she wants", why would she ask the question to begin with? Three upvotes at 5 points plus a downvote at -2 points still seems like a great deal for an easy question.

Comment: Why on earth are you thinking in terms of "deal?"  And the answer is NOT incorrect, since she never specified how much she wanted to move the title.  If your answer's better, than it'll get more votes; no need to push down others just to make yourself shine.

Comment: She did specify: "The title (Little Mrs. Married) should be in the turquoise area above the pink line & the subtitle (some things...) should be right under the pink line, but still above where it is now."

Comment: Which removing the padding did quite well.  If you go check out the link again and inspect the header with Firebug, you'll see that there's no longer any padding style, and the owner appears to be happy with where it's positioned.  And in all honesty, the difference between our answers is only 30px.

Comment: Actually, removing the padding all together put the subtitle above the "pink line", and she specifically asked otherwise... anyways, chill... I'm not trying to hurt your feelings... I'm just trying to give someone the answer they were looking for. LEts call it a day on this one... truce, ok?

Comment: So was I; is it really that big of a reason to downvote the answer?